# Pass parameters in window.location.href from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring

I have a datatable that on row click takes the value of a column of that row and should redirect to a page which takes that value as parameter.
This is the code :

```
var selected=[];
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function (){
var id = this.id;
var index = $.inArray(id, selected);
if (index === -1) 
{
    selected.push(id);
} else 
    {
    selected.splice(index, 1);
    }
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    });

$('#example').click(function (){
    var dataArr = [];
    var rows = $('tr.selected');
    var rowData = table.rows( rows ).data();

$.each($(rowData),function(key,value){
            dataArr.push(value["id"]);  

            });

            window.location ='users.html?-HERE THE ID SHOULD BE PASSED,which is in the array';
        });
```

And then I have to map accordingly in the Spring controller depending on the id.
But houw should I pass that parameter?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Store the position in the array you need in a variable and just concatenate it into the `window.location` call

```
var getArrayItem = dataArr[the_position_you_require]

window.location("users.html?" + getArrayItem);
```